# How to set the length of columnsep in a two columns document with paracol

Tags: two-column, rules, paracol

I'm using `paracol` to build a document composed by a header, followed by text in two columns, as in the example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{paracol,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\vspace{1cm}

\columnratio{0.29,0.69}
\begin{paracol}{2}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2em}


\begin{leftcolumn}
  \section{Section One}
  \lipsum [1-2]
\end{leftcolumn}

\begin{rightcolumn}
  \section{section two}
  \lipsum[3-4]
\end{rightcolumn}

\end{paracol}


\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

How can I remove the excess in the rule length above the section titles, but keeping the rule in the rest of the text? In other words: how can I set the rule length?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First I fixed the line-breaking problem with `\sloppy` (SOP for narrow columns).  Next I used `\globalcounter{section}` to fix the section numbers.  Finally I erased the top part of the line between the columns with white-out.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{paracol,lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\globalcounter{section}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\vspace{1cm}

\setcolumnwidth{0.29\textwidth,0.69\textwidth}
\begin{paracol}{2}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2em}

\begin{leftcolumn}
  \sloppy
  \section{Section One}
  \lipsum [1-2]
\end{leftcolumn}

\begin{rightcolumn}
  \section{section two}
  \leavevmode\llap{\smash{\color{white}\rule[\ht\strutbox]{\columnsep}{2cm}}}% erase top
  \lipsum[3-4]
\end{rightcolumn}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image: full page]

Comment: Under both MacTeX 2016 and 2017 (pretest) your code does not compile: `Undefined control sequence.
l.12 \columnratio
                 {0.29,0.69}`. Odd. I checked the documentation and everything looks right...

Comment: @sgmoye - In any case, it was being used incorrectly.

Comment: My bad. I found an old copy of paracol in my ~/texmf directory. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: I had to change the size of white thing covering the rule, but it worked well. Thanks!